# 'New Project' Failure: Android Studio 0.3.4

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a newb so perhaps I am missing something obvious, but I haven't been able to find anything on it and I am out of ideas...

java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

Android Studio Version: 0.3.4 Build 132.908450

Ubuntu 12.04

I get the following error message when completing the 'New Project' Wizard using all defaults:

"org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.add(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

Additionally, the project files are created in the home folder despite the IDE not launching.

I haven't been successful in locating the log, so any direction on that could possibly help the cause.

I installed gradle hoping that would fix it; no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: mine error says Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.filesystem.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystem, result is exactly as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to me when I upgraded Android Studio while using system Gradle 1.8 (not Gradle wrapper). The solution is to go to android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib folder and delete all Gradle 1.8 libraries (keep 1.9-rc-3 ones).